# how can I add a new column where there may be matches on an id field

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I currently have a table that contains an id, and a count of a criteria for that id field.  For example my table looks like this:

```
ID   Banana_count
1      13
2      23
3      56
```

The original counts came from a join and a query from other tables.

```
create FRUIT_TABLE as
select id, count (fruit) 
from  my_table a
where exists (select null from DATE_FED b
                where a.id = b.id
                 and date = (2/11/17)
                 and fruit_type = 'banana')
group by id;
```

My question is, how can i add other attributes to this particular table so that it looks like:

```
ID   Banana_count  Apple_count   Orange_count
1       13            35             22
2       23                           44
3       56
4                      33            55
5                                    11
```

I will have to add more ids to FRUIT_TABLE that may not already be in the current table, but for fruits that are currently associated with an id, i'd like to add them in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic use case for [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606):

```
merge into fruit_table
   using apple_table
   on (fruit_table.id = apple_table.id)
when matched then update set
   fruit_table.apples = apple_table.apples
when not matched then insert (id,apples)
   values(
      apple_table.id,
      apple_table.apples
   );
```

I have simplified the problem slightly so that you are inserting from a table that simply has ids and a count of apples, so that the structure of the merge is clearer.  But you can insert a subquery instead into the `using...` section of the statement to meet your actual requirements.

Comment: I created views based on my query, and then attempted to use the query you provided.  I am getting a ora-00969: missing ON keyword error.  The ON is there in my query though.  any ideas?

Comment: @user7002207 apologies, it looks like parentheses around the `on` clause are mandatory in Oracle (I'm a DB2 user and didn't realise that).  I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into something like the following [you didn't provide your table definitions, or other application or requirements constraints so an exact answer is not possible]:

```
create FRUIT_TABLE as
select id
, sum(case when fruit_type = 'banana' then 1 else 0 end ) Banana_count 
, sum(case when fruit_type = 'apple'  then 1 else 0 end ) apple_count 
, sum(case when fruit_type = 'orange' then 1 else 0 end ) orange_count 
from  my_table a
group by id;
```

Comment: This is the correct approach if you are free to simply create a new table, rather than adding a new column to an existing table.